# NumericupDown comparison Visual Studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have to make a quantile configuration and I have to set a condition so that the second value is higher than the first, the third value is higher than the second and so on. I am using numericupdowns and the value is set by the user. I tried to implement this code but it always shows a message box error even if the values are correct. This is my code so far (using Visual studio and C#):

[image: quantiles configuration]

```
decimal min = 1;

//when the first numeric is changed:
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numericUpDown1.Minimum = min;
    min = numericUpDown1.Value;
}

private void numericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    min++;
    numericUpDown2.Minimum = min;
    min = numericUpDown2.Value;
}

private void numericUpDown3_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    min++;
    numericUpDown3.Minimum = min;
    min = numericUpDown3.Value;
}


private void numericUpDown4_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    min++;
    numericUpDown4.Minimum = min;
    numericUpDown4.Maximum = 99;
}
private void button_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (
     numericUpDown1.Value > numericUpDown2.Value ||
      numericUpDown2.Value > numericUpDown3.Value ||
     numericUpDown3.Value > numericUpDown4.Value  )
    {
        MessageBox.Show(
          "Quantiles are not filled correctly",
          "The quantiles aren't filled in correctly", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        textBoxName.Select();
        DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The usage of the min variable does not make sense.  If the value for Nud1 changes then you need to set the minimum for Nud2, so numericUpdown2.Minimum = numericUpdown1.Value.  Etcetera.

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep all the NumericUpDown value inside a List or an array where you can manipulate them like a single entity trhough a loop.

Of course changing the minimum value of one of the numeric elements should be linked to a check for the current value inside that control because you can't have a current value lesser than the new minimum value.

So the first thing to do is to create a global variable  inside your form class where you keep the references to all the numeric controls that you want to synchronize

```
public class Form1
{
    private List<NumericUpDown> numbers = new List<NumericUpDown>();    
    public Form1 : Form
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        numbers.AddRange(new [] {n1, n2,n3,n4,n5});
    }
    ......
}
```

Now you can write a method like this one that adjust the minimum on all the numeric included in the list

```
private void UpdateMinimum()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < numbers.Count-1; x++)
    {
        if(numbers[x].Value > numbers[x+1].Value)
            numbers[x+1].Value = numbers[x].Value;
        numbers[x+1].Minimum = numbers[x].Value;
        
    }
}
```

finally you have all your NumericUpDown event ValueChanged call the same method

```
void numerics_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateMinimum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a condition so that the second value is higher than the first, the third value is higher than the second and so on, you can refer to the following code:

```
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numericUpDown1.Minimum = 1;
    }

    private void numericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numericUpDown2.Minimum = numericUpDown1.Value + 1;
    }

    private void numericUpDown3_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numericUpDown3.Minimum = numericUpDown2.Value + 1;

    }

    private void numericUpDown4_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numericUpDown4.Minimum = numericUpDown3.Value + 1;
        numericUpDown4.Maximum = 99;
    }

    private void button_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (
            numericUpDown1.Value > numericUpDown2.Value ||
            numericUpDown2.Value > numericUpDown3.Value ||
            numericUpDown3.Value > numericUpDown4.Value)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
              "Quantiles are not filled correctly",
              "The quantiles aren't filled in correctly", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textBoxName.Select();
            DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
            return;
        }
    }
```

**Here is the test result:**
[image]